# How to overcome Python fonts (Pygame) not being loaded

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have moved on to messing with Pygame recently, and I started following tutorials. Everything has ran fine up until I reached a program that looks like so:

```
"""
 A python graphics introduction.

 This simple program draws lines at a 45 degree angle from one side
 of the screen to the other.
"""

# Import a library of functions called 'pygame'
import pygame
from pygame import font

# Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
size = (400, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Intro to Graphics")

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Loop as long as done == False
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    # All drawing code happens after the for loop and but
    # inside the main while not done loop.

    # Clear the screen and set the screen background
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # Select the font to use, size, bold, italics
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)

    # Render the text. "True" means anti-aliased text. 
    # Black is the color. This creates an image of the 
    # letters, but does not put it on the screen
    text = font.render("My text", True, BLACK)

    # Put the image of the text on the screen at 250x250
    screen.blit(text, [250, 250])

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    # This MUST happen after all the other drawing commands.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # This limits the while loop to a max of 60 times per second.
    # Leave this out and we will use all CPU we can.
    clock.tick(60)


# Be IDLE friendly
pygame.quit()
```

When ran I get an error at *font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)* that looks like:

```
RuntimeWarning: use font: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found
(ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found)
  pygame.font.init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IntroGraphics.py", line 15, in <module>
    pygame.font.init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
NotImplementedError: font module not available
(ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found)
```

I have looked on here for an answer, and the only other post about it involves 32-bit Pygame with 64-bit Python. I have made sure both of them are running 32-bit (Despite the fact it's a 64-bit machine. Pygame is only 32-bit.). I am running Python 2.7.9 Fresh Install

Other places say it's a problem with SDL, but I am inexperienced with SDL and I wouldn't know what to do.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Have you installed sdl_ttf? http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/

Comment: Indeed, when you Homebrew pygame it comes with it. I even installed SDL2 just to be sure. The problem is it says "Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Verisons/A/SDL_ttf not found" but I can go there manually and find it.

Answer (score 0):

The fonts that are available to pygame might be different on different computers.  I suggest seeing if the font you want to use is included on your computer.  You can see the all the available fonts with this command:

```
pygame.font.get_fonts()
# returns a list of available fonts
```

You can also get the system's default fort by using this command:

```
pygame.font.get_default_font()
# returnes the name of the default font
```

You can use this code to check your font:

```
if 'Calibri' in pygame.font.get_fonts():
    font_name = 'Calibri'
else:
    font_name = pygame.font.get_default_font()
```